# Автоматическое удаление индексов в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, index

Можно ли  находить и автоматически чистить индексы в бд?

По типу процедура которая видит что reltuples,idx_tup_read,idx_scan пустые, дальше берет имя индекса и как-то удаляет его...

Comment: [Index Maintenance](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance)

Comment: как это поможет ?

Answer (score 0):

```
do $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select relnamespace::regnamespace as namespace, relname
        from pg_index i
        join pg_class c on c.oid = i.indexrelid
        where not indisvalid
    loop
        execute format('drop index %s.%s', rec.namespace, rec.relname);
        -- optionally:
        -- raise notice '%', format('drop index %s.%s', rec.namespace, rec.relname);
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: это ответ на мой вопрос